# No action was found on the controller 'Callback' that matches the request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm literally going crazy trying to fix this but nothing I do seems to make a difference. When I navigate to `localhost:3978/api/callback` it throws

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3978/api/callback'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Callback' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

This is the controller in my Controllers/CallbackController.cs

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Autofac;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace VSTF_RD_Bot.Controllers
{
    public class CallbackController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Callback")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Callback([FromUri] string state, [FromUri] string code)
        {
            //parse out the userId and convoId from states parameter
            string[] states = state.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string userId = states[0];
            string conversationId = states[1];

            // Check if the bot is running against emulator
            var connectorType = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal ? ConnectorType.Emulator : ConnectorType.Cloud;

            // Exchange the Facebook Auth code with Access toekn
            var token = await AdHelpers.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(userId, conversationId, code, "redirect_uri");

            // Create the message that is send to conversation to resume the login flow
            var msg = new Message
            {
                Text = $"token:{token}",
                From = new ChannelAccount { Id = userId },
                To = new ChannelAccount { Id = Constants.botId },
                ConversationId = conversationId
            };



            var reply = await Conversation.ResumeAsync(Constants.botId, userId, conversationId, msg, connectorType: connectorType);

            // Remove the pending message because login flow is complete
            IBotData dataBag = new JObjectBotData(reply);
            PendingMessage pending;
            if (dataBag.PerUserInConversationData.TryGetValue("pendingMessage", out pending))
            {
                dataBag.PerUserInConversationData.RemoveValue("pendingMessage");
                var pendingMessage = pending.GetMessage();
                reply.To = pendingMessage.From;
                reply.From = pendingMessage.To;

                // Send the login success asynchronously to user
                var client = Conversation.ResumeContainer.Resolve<IConnectorClient>(TypedParameter.From(connectorType));
                await client.Messages.SendMessageAsync(reply);

                return Request.CreateResponse("You are now logged in! Continue talking to the bot.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Callback is called with no pending message as a result the login flow cannot be resumed.
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new InvalidOperationException("Cannot resume!"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

This is my webApiconfig.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace VSTF_RD_Bot
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Json settings
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            };

            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mate the params are like this `api/callback?state=something&code=234234234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Callback/{state}/{code}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Callback(string state, string code)
{
```

and request url

```
"localhost:3978/api/Callback/samplestate/samplecode"
```

Comment: the thing is the state and code are `params api/callback?state=something&code=234234234`